# Font used as stripe.com logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am trying to find out, but I am having a hard time. I would like to know what the font type used to create the logo at http://stripe.com is? Does anyone happen to know?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FF Fago](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/fontfont/ff-fago/), they sent me an email with the font name

Answer (score 1):

Running the font through [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) gave me [CamingoDos Pro Condensed Extra Bold](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/jan-fromm/camingo-dos-pro-condensed/extra-bold/) which has a very similar feel to the Stripe.com font.

And while this isn't the font either, the site does use a lot of [Helvetica Neue](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/helvetica-neue/)/[Helvetica](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/helvetica/)

It's most definitely not [Interstate Ultrablack](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/font_bureau/interstate_ultra_black/?&fg=000000&bg=ffffff&sample_size=36&sample_text=Stripe&ft=liga) as Thiago suggested, as it's much too bulky and the letter shapes are very different.

Hopefully someone will be able to provide more insight.

Comment: FF Fago, they sent me an email with the font name!